# Including line breaks in tufte_handout code blocks?

Tags: r, r-markdown, literate-programming, tufte

I'm using `tufte::tufte_handout` in rmarkdown. I would like to preserve newlines in code blocks, but these seem to disappear. When I use usual `pdf_document`, the spaces are preserved. Is there any workaround, so that I can use `tufte_handout` but still have formatted code?

For example, when I compile this rmarkdown to pdf,

````
    ---
    title: "Test"
    output:
      #pdf_document
      tufte::tufte_handout:
        latex_engine: xelatex
    ---
    
    This is a test.
    
    ```{r}
    z <- expand.grid(
      x = seq(10),
      y = seq(10)
    )
    ```
````

the output puts entire `expand.grid` on a single line. If I compile using `pdf_document` instead, the newlines are preserved.

[image: tufte_output]